# Convert a String array to Dictionary in Swift, how?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a `string array` and I wish to convert to a `Dictionary` using the `array` `index` as the key in the `Dictionary`.

```
array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

convert to:

```
dictionary = [0 : "string1", 1 : "string2", 2 : "string3"]
```

Comment: `let dictionary = array.enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.offset] = $1.element }`

Comment: you can also use Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:) initializer and pass a new array from your array enumerated `let dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Array(array.enumerated()))`

Comment: thanks Leo I appreciate your help, how can I cast the Dictionary to be [String : Any], your solution return [Int : String], I need the key of the Dictionary to be a String as this is being pushed up to Firebase DB and its throwing an error as its not expecting an Int as the Key

Comment: `let dictionary = array.enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[String($1.offset)] = $1.element }`

Comment: Why do you want the value type to be Any if the array only contains strings? you should probably use `[String:String]`

Comment: If you really need [String:Any] you just need to cast the elements to Any `let dictionary = array.enumerated().reduce(into: [:]) { $0[String($1.offset)] = $1.element as Any }`

Comment: another approach to get `[String:String]` using the dictionary initialiser  `let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: array.enumerated().map{(String($0),$1)})`

Comment: for `[String:Any]` using the dictionary initialiser  `let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: array.enumerated().map{(String($0),$1 as Any)})`

Comment: thanks so much @LeoDabus this has really helped. The data its now in the format I need it to upload to Firebase DB - thanks again.

Comment: I've updated the duplicated question link if you would like to check the extension now returns `[String:Element]` for Swift 4 as well